# C: Anyway to load parameters into a system() call

Tags: c, variables, arguments, system

Is it possible to put arguments in a systems call?

something like

```
system("rm %s %s", string1, string2)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The prototype for the `system` function is:

```
int system(const char *command);
```

so, no. But, how about:

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "rm %s %s", target1, target2);
system(buffer);
```

Comment: Also I'd like to point out the existence of `asprintf` which conveniently allocates the necessary buffer for you (which you need to `free` afterwards). Saves you from calculating the buffer size yourself.

Comment: @DarkDust: `asprintf` is a GNU & *BSD extension, though. Not necessarily a bad thing, but still..

Comment: @Michael Foukarakis: `snprintf` is a C99 function for that matter. That's usually worth mentioning.

Comment: I really hate it when people would say: doing this is a bad idea, or doing that is wrong and do not specify WHY. @JeremyP why using system() is bad idea? :P

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
private:    
char command[128];
char temp[10] = {'"','I','P','v','4','"'}; //snprintf();
public:
int SysInfo(){
    snprintf(command,sizeof(command), "ipconfig | find  %s > save.log",temp);
    system(command);
}
```

Comment: That is C++, but the question is specifically about C