# How to use command line variables with system()?

Tags: c

I have tried to do the following:
`system("SMC_v3 %s %s %s %s %s %s %s", trials, Np, Ni, Nn, w, Structure, V);`
to call SMC_v3.exe with command line variables.

But there are too many variables.
How can I use system() with the command line variables?
(this needs to go in a loop)

Comment: I have tried using system() but it doesn't like the command line variables.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm not quite clear on what you're asking. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Nope, and in any case, pretty sure this should have been closed anyway because it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482832/c-anyway-to-load-parameters-into-a-system-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`system` does not understand the same `%s` specifiers as `printf` does. You will have to build the string first, for example using `sprintf`, and then call `system` with that string.

Comment: Note that doing this is usually **extremely** unsafe unless you have strong control over the contents being filled in to the format fields, because the resulting string is interpreted by the shell. It's much better to use `fork`+`execve`, `posix_spawn`, or the equivalents on other non-POSIX-like systems.

Comment: @R.. Indeed.  Also, don't use `system()` in an executable that you make setuid in order to allow non-root users to run a command as root.  That's usually a very effective way of providing a privilege-escalation exploit, along with all the problems you've already mentioned.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: suid is only a small special case that (hopefully) most users don't do. The more common vulnerability is software that runs as the normal user but obtained the strings from a document file from possibly-untrusted sources or from an http request to an untrusted site, etc.