# Is there any function in C that is equivalent to icacls command prompt?

Tags: c, windows, active-directory, ntfs

I need to change the permissions on a folder(in a windows computer) using the userPrincipalName or sAMAccountName or SID of user from a different AD domain. I am able to do this using icacls in the command prompt (of the domain in which the user exists) but need to do it using a C program that runs from a different domain instead.

Comment: The lazy way is to call `icacls` with [`system()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5482832/11683)...

Comment: in brief, call [`GetNamedSecurityInfoW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-getnamedsecurityinfow): `DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION`; [`SetEntriesInAclW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setentriesinaclw), `TRUSTEE_IS_NAME`, `TRUSTEE_IS_USER`; and then [`SetNamedSecurityInfoW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setnamedsecurityinfow).

Comment: @eryksun Thanks a lot, your suggestion helped me get started. But since I am setting the permissions on a shared folder from a different domain, SetEntriesInAclW does not recognize the user.

Comment: Did you try using the SID with `TRUSTEE_IS_SID`?

Comment: @erykson Yes, I tried using TRUSTEE_IS_SID. But since user and SID are in a different domain the program is not working. Is there a way to add an entry to the ACL without verifying the existence of the user? or maybe give admin credentials programmatically to connect to the other domain so that the user is recognized.?